# Dismiss Bootstrap 4.21 Popover when clicked outside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to close Popover (using Bootstrap 4.21) when clicked outside it. I have found some examples but I use different approach - popover is linked to external  element and not on clicked element.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="view();">Popover</a>    
    <p style="width:200px" id="my_popover">Popover displayed here</p>

<script>
  function    view(){
  var data = ''+
        '    <div class="list links-list">'+
        '      <div class="list-group">'+
        '      <a id="link1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Left Page 1</a>'+
        '      <a id="link2" href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Left Page 2</a>'+
        '    </div>';
    $("#my_popover").popover({
          html : true,
          placement: 'bottom',
          trigger: 'focus',
          content: data
    });
    $("#my_popover").popover('toggle');
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to close Popover when clicked outside?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try This:

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
  if($(e.target).is('#popper')){
    var data = ''+
        '    <div class="list links-list>'+
        '      <div class="list-group">'+
        '      <a id="link1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Left Page 1</a>'+
        '      <a id="link2" href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Left Page 2</a>'+
        '    </div>';
    $("#my_popover").popover({
      html : true,
      placement: 'bottom',
      trigger: 'focus',
      content: data
    });
    $("#my_popover").popover('toggle');
  }
  else if($(e.target).is('.popover-body')){
    return;
  }
  else if($(e.target).is('#link1')){
    return;
  }
  else if($(e.target).is('#link2')){
    return;
  }
  else {
    $('#my_popover').popover('hide');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="popper">Popover</a>    
<p style="width:200px" id="my_popover">Popover displayed here</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
  if($(e.target).is('#popper')){
    var data = ''+
        '    <div class="list links-list>'+
        '      <div class="list-group">'+
        '      <a id="link1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Left Page 1</a>'+
        '      <a id="link2" href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Left Page 2</a>'+
        '    </div>';
    $("#my_popover").popover({
      html : true,
      placement: 'bottom',
      trigger: 'focus',
      content: data
    });
    $("#my_popover").popover('toggle');
  }
  else if($(e.target).is('.popover-body')){
    return;
  }
  else if($(e.target).is('.list-group-item')){
    return;
  }
  else {
    $('#my_popover').popover('hide');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="popper">Popover</a>    
<p style="width:200px" id="my_popover">Popover displayed here</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes it works, but closed it also popover when clicked inside it. I need to keep popover opened when clicking inside it and closed when clicked outside it. Thank you.

Comment: @user2666909 you can use `event.target` to find the element on which click event is happening and if it returns other than Popover link or Popover div then `$("#my_popover").popover('hide');` should run. try this I think it will solve your problem. :)

Comment: thank you but if I would know how to do that then I wouldn't not ask :( can you please update this example : http://code.reloado.com/oeasyrik1/224/edit#preview with your code, please?

Comment: thank you, yes it works but when you click on list-group-item inside popover, it is closed again. Maybe I need to ask like this: how to close popover when click outside of popover , on body? Because popover can contain other elements, like button, input, table etc. Thank you.

Comment: @user2666909 I have updated my code again ! check if this is what you need.

Comment: yes I can tell you it works but if I have 100 elements inside popover, I need to put all of them inside JS (else if ...).. I created another example here: http://code.reloado.com/oeasyrik1/225/edit#preview and I think it solve problem in general.. I added id to html element and it looks it works.. now I can have any number of elements inside popover.. can you please check is it OK?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187037/discussion-between-partho63-and-user2666909).

Comment: @user2666909 Your code seems to be ok. But in my opinion it would be better if you give a class to all of your items and then on javascript check for that class only. this way you wouldn't need multiple `else if` for each items.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="popover" href="#">Test</a>

$("#popover").popover({
    container: "body",
    content: getContent,
    html: true,
    placement: "bottom",
    trigger: "manual"
}).click(function(event) {
    $("#popover").popover('show');
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $("#popover").popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, I created example with your code here: http://code.reloado.com/oeasyrik1/223/edit but it doe snot work.. also it does not produce any error. can you please take a look?